# jQuery Datatables highlighting row

Tags: datatables

I'm using datatables version 1.9.4 and am having a problem with adding a class to certain rows.

I have multiple datatables, all with class 'display'. I'm using jQuery tabs to display each datatable on a separate tab.

All is working well, except I want to add a class to a table row depending on the column values; if column 6 is less than column 14, I want to add myClass.

I've found suggestions to use fnRowCallback, but I'm getting random results, such as sometimes if column 6 is less than column 14, myClass gets added correctly, but other times if column 14 is less than column 6 myClass still gets added!

This doesn't happen for all rows though, so it's pretty random.

Here's the code I'm using

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.display').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "sScrollY": "300px",
    "sAjaxSource": "ajax.php",
    "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ipS>',
    "oScroller": {
        "loadingIndicator": true
    },
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData ) {
      var $nRow = $(nRow);
      if (aData[6] < aData[14]) {
        $nRow.addClass("myClass");
      }
      return nRow
    }
  });

});
```

Is there something wrong with what I've done, or is it because I'm using multiple tables?

Comment: This problem is definitely to do with the fact I have tables on different tabs. I've added an alert(aData[6]) and alert(aData[14]) inside the fnRowCallback function, and I'm getting aData[6] values from the table on tab 2, and strangely aData[14] values from the table on tab 4! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this working, but there is probably a cleaner way, so if anyone knows of a better way of doing this, please let me know!

I'm looping through all the rows for each table once the table has been drawn.....

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    for (var i = 0, row; row = oSettings.nTable.rows[i]; i++) {
        price = Number(row.cells[4].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
        average = Number(row.cells[6].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
         if (price < average) {
             row.className = row.className + " myClass";
         }
    }
}
```